# In background script, chrome.runtime is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dojo

I'm not able to access events inside my Background script. (I have disabled all my other extension, Chrome version: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Download the extension zip file, this also doesn't work same issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2PMiyi-mpArcmlwVTl0UUFjNTA/view?usp=sharing

Manifest:

```
"background": {
    "page": "client_base/host/chrome/index.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://mail.google.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "/gmail_ext/content_script.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "/gmail_ext/loader.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

Content script:

```
var getContactsPort = chrome.runtime.connect('getContacts');
    getContactsPort.postMessage({greeting: "hello"});
    getContactsPort.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        alert(message);
    });
```

Background script (which is called from page with script tag, via Dojo)

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (getContactsPort) {
                getContactsPort.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                    getContactsPort.postMessage({status: msg.greeting + ' world'});
                });
            });
```

DevTools showing `chrome.runtime` as undefined:

[image: DevTools showing <code>chrome.runtime</code> as undefined:]

Comment: i will share GIF video of the issue if you want, cant share code its not a single file but an entire Dojo project

Comment: @wOxxOm zip file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2PMiyi-mpArcmlwVTl0UUFjNTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can only reproduce when the devtools debugger for the background page is opened. The problem can be circumvented by using normal breakpoints in Sources panel of devtools. BTW you can submit a bug report on https://crbug.com, just don't forget to mention the exact steps required to reproduce and the extension itself.

Comment: By the "normal breakpoints" I mean you need to remove `debugger;` statement and set a breakpoint via UI by clicking on the line number column.

Comment: still doesnt matter if I use breakpoint or not, it doesnt work. The listener callback always received "undefined"

`getContactsPort.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
        alert(message);
    });`

Comment: That's a different issue, obviously. The zip file you shared doesn't demonstrate that. Maybe you didn't reload the web page after reloading the extension?

Comment: I did, i will checking again. I think somewhere in Dojo project there is another event listener which is overwriting mine

Comment: @wOxxOm the undefined was actually an error which states : `chrome.runtime.lastError`

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to answer but you can use this instead -

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, (tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data: 'hi'});
});
```